# RecyclerView - how to animate view visibility?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am looking for way to change view visibility (from gone to visible) inside RecyclerView.

I tried to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to my `ConstraintLayout` (root of RecyclerViews items) and change programmatically visibility of its child.

It works quite well, but first few items are weird - I mean that they completely disappear and show once again instead of animating only visibility of one view. Rest of them are good.

Is there any solution? Do you need any additional informations? 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you try notifyItemChanged method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default `ÌtemAnimator` to your `RecyclerView`

```
your_recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```